# GStreamer won't show video

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I ran Gstreamer tutorial's [example code](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c#building-the-tutorials) in both my own 2 computers.

- One PC was install Ubuntu 20.04.2, GPU Nvidia GTX 1050Ti
- And the remain one (i.e laptop) was install Ubuntu 18.04.5, with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M

And the result when built successfully `./basic-tutorial-1` was:

- the ubuntu 20 PC can show the video in the display.
- but the ubuntu 18 laptop is not display anything, or even any error logs.

Is there any Gstreamer's problem relate to OS.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with installation:

try:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-tools
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
```

Comment: I think in my case, that is not a solution. Because in my own computers, I installed with using the same command `apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio`